# Formgroup doesn't display inside a bootstrap card

Tags: angular, forms, html-table, angular-template

I've got a somewhat complicated Angular HTML template with two tables that should both include a form. The intent is that this form will display as a row at the bottom of each table.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="jumbotron">{{ dateString }}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let item of day | async">
        <h6>On this day, you: </h6>
        <p><strong>Burned</strong> {{ item.caloriesBurned }} calories</p>
        <p><strong>Gained</strong> {{ item.caloriesGained }} calories</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card col-sm-6">
                <div class="card-header"><span class="headers">Sessions</span>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addBtns">New Activity</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Activity</th>
                                <th scope="col">Calories Burned</th>
                                <th scope="col">Duration (Minutes)</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let session of sessions | async; let i = index">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ session.activity }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ session.caloriesBurned }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ session.duration }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container>
                                <tr>
                                    <form [formGroup]="activityForm" class="form-group"
                                        (ngSubmit)="onActivitySubmit(activityForm.values)">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <td><label for="activity">Activity</label><input id="activity"
                                                    formControlName="activity" type="text" placeholder="Activity"
                                                    class="form-control"></td>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <td><label for="caloriesBurned">Calories Burned</label><input
                                                    id="caloriesBurned" formControlName="caloriesBurned" type="number"
                                                    placeholder="Calories Burned" class="form-control"></td>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <td><label for="duration">Duration</label><input id="duration"
                                                    formControlName="duration" type="number"
                                                    placeholder="Duration in minutes" class="form-control"></td>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
                                    </form>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-container>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card col-sm-6">
                <div class="card-header"><span class="headers">Meals</span>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addBtns">New Meal</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Calories Gained</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let meal of meals | async">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ meal.name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ meal.calories }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-container>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I want to display this `activityForm` at the bottom of one of these tables, however, when I try to run this template, it doesn't actually render the form. Looking at it in the inspector, the rest of the page is fine, even down to the containing `<tr>`, but the form inside appears grayed-out in the inspector. Every element exists and renders properly right down to the table, which exists inside the `<tr>` but just doesn't seem to want to render.

When I moved the form outside of the `<div class="card col-sm-6">` tag, it rendered correctly and works as expected. I've checked the CSS rules on the form and found this:

[image]

This "box model properties" section seems to have a `display: none`, which I would assume is the issue, but when I manually add a different `display` rule, the new rule doesn't take effect, but also doesn't gray-out, even with a `!important` tag.

I'm not sure if my `.ts` file could be messing with this, but I've pasted the relevant parts anyway:

```
export class DayDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  mealForm: FormGroup;
  activityForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public builder: FormBuilder) { 
      this.mealForm = this.builder.group({
        name: '',
        calories: 0
      })
      this.activityForm = this.builder.group({
        activity: '',
        caloriesBurned: 0,
        duration: 0
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably because you have not followed correct table html syntax. You can't place a `div` after a `tr` and before a `td`. The same will be true with a form. You could wrap the table in a form as one solution and place the divs inside each td.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment your table syntax is incorrect, you could use the following instead.

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>placeholder</label>
                    <input/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>placeholder</label>
                    <input/>
                </div>
            </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```